# Failed to install package "rfm"

Tags: r, install.packages

I tried installing package "rfm" using install.packages("rfm") and devtools::install_github("rsquaredacademy/rfm") but failed in both attempts. See below and please help.

> install.packages("rfm")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/stang/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   also installing the dependency ‘rlang’

Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘rlang’
  These will not be installed
installing the source package ‘rfm’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rfm_0.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1415439 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

ERROR: dependency 'rlang' is not available for package 'rfm'
* removing 'C:/Users/stang/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/rfm'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4RE/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\stang\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\stang\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm4YOIe/downloaded_packages/rfm_0.1.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rfm’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\stang\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm4YOIe\downloaded_packages’

> ## install.packages("devtools")
>
> devtools::install_github("rsquaredacademy/rfm")
>   Downloading GitHub repo rsquaredacademy/rfm@master
>   from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rsquaredacademy/rfm/zipball/master
>   Installing rfm
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4RE/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
>     "C:/Users/stang/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpm4YOIe/devtools10c41f69459c/rsquaredacademy-rfm-64bdbe9" --library="C:/Users/stang/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"  \
>     --install-tests

ERROR: dependency 'rlang' is not available for package 'rfm'
* removing 'C:/Users/stang/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/rfm'
Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: It looks like you are using an older version of R (version 3.2). Any reason you haven't upgraded to 3.5? That's likely to help with the package installation as CRAN doesn't make it super easy to install packages for older versions of R.

Comment: thank you so much! I was able to install the package. But running into another problem when using the function rfm_table_order with error message below. I will post a separate question to seek help. Thanks again!!  
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: <U+0091>max<U+0092> not meaningful for factors.

Comment: That’s really a separate issue. You can open a new question but make sure to include a reproducible example so we can see what you are passing in to these functions.

Comment: Will do. Thank you again!!